Trying to do react-native bridge module I keep getting dependency couldn't be found
This is my first time trying to do react-native bridge. Problem is it always says it couldnt find the dependency, irrespective of my integration, I should be able to download the dependency right? I am trying to bridge:
https://developer.imepay.com.np/#/andriod-sdk
I am not being able to implement the dependecy:
implementation 'com.swifttechnology.imepaysdk:payment-service:4.0.1

In my main/java/imepayintegration:
ImepayModule.java:
package com.reactnativeimepay;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Promise;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.swifttechnology.imepaysdk.IMEPayment;
import com.swifttechnology.imepaysdk.IMEPaymentCallback;
import com.swifttechnology.imepaysdk.ENVIRONMENT;

public class ImepayModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
    private final ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

    public ImepayModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        this.reactContext = reactContext;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "ImepayModule";
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void performPayment(String merchantCode, String merchantName, String module,
                               String username, String password, String referenceValue,
                               String amount, String merchantTransactionRecordingUrl,
                               Promise promise) {
        IMEPayment imePayment = new IMEPayment(reactContext, ENVIRONMENT.TEST);

        imePayment.performPayment(merchantCode,
                merchantName,
                merchantTransactionRecordingUrl,
                amount,
                referenceValue,
                module,
                username,
                password,
                new IMEPaymentCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int responseCode, String responseDescription,
                                          String transactionId, String msisdn,
                                          String amount, String refId) {
                        promise.resolve("Payment successful");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(int responseCode, String responseDescription) {
                        promise.reject("ERROR", responseDescription);
                    }
                });
    }
}


ImepayPackage.java:
package com.reactnativeimepay;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

public class ImepayPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(new ImepayModule(reactContext));
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}


